# Dataviz pie chart label's lines cross each other

Tags: kendo-ui, pie-chart, kendo-dataviz

I am using Kendo pie chart to display some data. But i am having issue shown in below picture, label's lines cross each other. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: 2016 and still having this problem

Answer (score -2):

Have you managed to sort your problem?  If not, see documentation with regards to the position and alignment. [Labels Sample](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/pie-charts/pie-labels.html)